# How to catch ActiveMQAddressFullException?

Tags: jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

Using WildFly with embedded ActiveMQ Artemis as the JMS implementation. The queue is setup with a fixed memory size and `FAIL` action if queue is full. I need to be able to catch the resulting exception so the clients stop sending new messages. However, the exception doesn't seem to occur when calling send, but at the end of the transaction a few methods up. I'm not sure how to handle this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a transaction then the messages are *not* actually sent when you call `send` on the JMS `MessageProducer`. They messages are only sent when the transaction is committed. Batching multiple operations together like this is one of the main features of transactions. If there is a problem sending the messages at the point of committing the transaction then the transaction commit will fail, but the specific `MessageProducer` which "sent" the messages will have no knowledge of it. You'll need to either stop using transactions or inform the sender of the problem another way (which will only be retroactive).

If you are *only* using transactions because you need to know the message reached the queue successfully and you don't need group multiple JMS operations into one logical unit then you can stop using transactions and either:

1. Ensure you're sending durable (i.e. persistent) messages.
2. Set `blockOnNonDurableSend=true` in your client URL is you're sending non-durable (i.e. non-persistent) messages.

In either case the client will wait for a response from the broker that the message was successfully received. You can read more about this in [the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/send-guarantees.html#non-transactional-message-sends).

If your client times out waiting for a response then that likely means the broker didn't receive the message and you are OK to send it again. However, in certain cases the broker (or the network) might fail *after* the message was successfully received but *before* the response could reach the client. In those situations if the client sends the message again it may result in a duplicate. To mitigate against the risk of duplicates you can set a duplicate ID on the message and use duplicate detection on the broker. You can read more about duplicate detection in [the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/duplicate-detection.html).

In any case, whether the messages are actually sent when `send` is invoked or later when `commit` is invoked the messages should *not* actually be sent if `max-size-bytes` has been reached since you're using `FAIL`.

Comment: Thanks. We do need to continue using transactions, since we need to know if the message was queued or not. Given that, do you have any suggestions on how we can implement some kind of flow control. The issue we have is that when the system is heavily loaded all the messages are being paged out to disk and will eventually fill up the whole disk. We need to find a way to programmatically not queue more requests if the queue if already "full". Unfortunately this kind of use case does not seem to be supported at all in the standard JMS API.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Still need to digest this and see how to apply it within a WildFly context and our application. Will mark as correct anyway.